# UITableViewController in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a plain project with blank `UIView`. Later, when I'm get some useful information from my serwer i would like to create UIView or `UITableView`.

I have a class:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
}
```

And I have `AppDelegate`, `ViewController` and `.xib` file.

What i should do to load a `UITableView`? I should unload my standard ViewController in AppDelegate or Load TableView inside View as a Subview (possible?) Or i should throw out xib file at all ? Of course everything i want to do in to my Views has to be programically not using IB.

In my app i want to create both, depends on receiving data.

Comment: yes you can do it , when get data from service allocate uitableview add it on your UIView  as subviewset the delegate of tableview to self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a uiview and load the uitableview inside the uiview (rootViewController)
with that said, I assume you are using interface builder (IB) which makes things much more visual and easy to manipulate visually.
If needed I will add the relevant code.

Comment: No, as i said screen will depends on data, so i cannot use a IB.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "depends on data". if data requires a tableview , load it into your view and populate it with data (programmatically) , if not - load what ever is needed. the reason for loading a tableview inside a viewController is the ability to add other elements "around" the uitableview

Comment: OK, so if i understand correctly in my AppDelegate first i Load UIView, and then UITableView into it. So i had to even had my class with TableViewController?

Comment: yes, like Adali code, UITableView tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bound];
[self.view addSubView:tableView];

Answer (score 2):

you can push a UITableViewController Or a UIViewController contain a UITableView

or juse add a tableView to current view of UIViewController

```
UITableView tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bound];
[self.view addSubView:tableView];
```

Answer (score 2):

write this code in .h file

```
     @interface SelectPeopleViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource> {

      UITableView *tableView;

       }

       @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
```

than add datasource and delegate of Uitableview to your File's Owner

write this code in .m file

```
          #pragma mark Table view methods

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return 1;
      }

   // Customize the number of rows in the table view.
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return 5;
          }

      // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      }

// Set up the cell...
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Cell Row #%d", [indexPath row]];

    return cell;
    }

         - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// open a alert with an OK and cancel button
     NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clicked on row #%d", [indexPath row]];
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertString message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add UITableView to an UIViewController's UIVIew if there is a necessity to add other controls to a view.

If there is nothing other than a tableview in your viewcontroller's view then you can make it an subclass of UITableViewController as well.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to clear one thing. So if i load UITableView in UIView i don't get compiler error? In my project i get one, so i figure out that is becouse i try to load TableView into UIView, and not UIViewController.

Comment: You can not load UITableView in UIViewController, it is after all added to UIView. Can you tell me what is that warning you are getting?

Comment: Thanks, you, already responce to my error ;) Now if i know that you post above i can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableView in your UIViewController

```
   @interface MyViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
   {
        IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;
   }
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;
```

Then in your viewController xib file create a tableview in view. connect it to the mytableview in files owner.Also DONT FORGET to set delegate and data source to files owner.

Later in your .m file create these functions and modify it according to your data.

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       return 1; //how many sections in your tableView
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:       (NSInteger)section
   {

       return [myArray count]; //how many rows you have
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = @"title";

return cell;
   }

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       NSLog("%d.row selected",indexPath.row);
   }
```